# Jquery selecting a certain column with multiple tables

Tags: jquery

The following var `stepID` is not working for me how I anticipated.

I have two separate tables on my view. Both tables have some inputs in them with `.pClass`.

If I am in the second table and a key up event occurs, it seems to be getting the input value from the first table and not the second table. But I need it to look at the same table that the keyup event happened in, not the first.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.pClass', function () {
  var detailRowID = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').html();
  var stepID = $('tr').children('th')
                      .eq($(this).closest('td').index())
                      .children('input').val();
  var percent = $(this).val(); 
});
```

Comment: `$('tr')` should be `$(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: gives me undefined. [link]https://jsbin.com/yizigawova/edit?js,output

Comment: This link shows it grabbing first tables input.  Click in one of the 2nd tables highlighted fields.  I need this to show the second tables th number, not the first table.  Same with 3rd table.  It grabs first table numbers https://jsbin.com/gokupigupu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: That's the most disgusting code I've ever seen.

Comment: and yet you cannot answer.....go back to bed, son

Comment: `th` isn't a child of the current `tr`, it's a child of the first `tr` in the closest `table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `th` you want is in the `colNames` row of the closest `<table>`.

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.pClass', function() {
   var detailRowID = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').html();
   var stepID = $(this).closest('table').find('tr.colNames').children('th').eq($(this).closest('td').index()).children('input').val();

   alert(stepID);

 });
```

```css
body {
  /*background-color:darkgrey;*/
}
table {
  font-family: 'Tahoma';
  font-size: 70%;
  width: unset!important;
}
table th.shrink {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table th.wrap {
  word-wrap: initial;
}
table td.shrink {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table td.expand {
  width: 99%;
}
tr.titleRow td {
  background-color: #3e3f3a!important;
  color: white;
  text-indent: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #3e3f3a;
  vertical-align: middle!important;
  padding: 1px 4px 1px 4px !important;
}
th {
  font-size: 95%;
  /*background-color:transparent!important;*/
  background-color: #93C54B!important;
}
td {
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px!important;
}
.colNames:hover {
  cursor: default!important;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent!important;
}
.WBS {
  width: 150px!important;
}
.ActivityCode {
  width: 10px!important;
  text-align: center;
}
.ActivityName {
  width: 100px!important;
}
.PTTDescription {
  width: 200px!important;
}
.OriginalBudget {
  width: 50px!important;
  text-align: center;
}
.PCN {
  width: 25px!important;
  text-align: center;
}
.ControlBudget {
  width: 50px!important;
  text-align: center;
}
[class$="chgWidth"] {
  background-color: #CCC!important;
  width: 75px!important;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: xx-small!important;
}
input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
.input-sm-np {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*padding:0px,0px,0px,0px!important;*/
  width: 45px;
  /*background: url(/images/percent.png) no-repeat scroll 1% 1%;*/
  /*padding-left: 30px;*/
  text-align: right;
}
.percent {
  text-align: center;
}
[class="Cell+1"],
[class="Cell+3"],
[class="Cell+4"],
[class="Cell+5"] {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="titleRow">
      <td colspan="100%">J11 - Project List, Equipment List, Drawing and Spec Registers, Hold Log - Multidiscipline</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="colNames">
      <th class="r_id
                 " id="r_id" hidden="true">
        r_id
      </th>
      <th class="WBS
                 " id="WBS">
        WBS
      </th>
      <th class="ActivityCode
                 " id="Activity Code">
        Activity Code
      </th>
      <th class="PTTDescription
                 " id="PTT Description">
        PTT Description
      </th>
      <th class="OriginalBudget
                 " id="Original Budget">
        Original Budget
      </th>
      <th class="PCN
                 " id="PCN">
        PCN
      </th>
      <th class="ControlBudget
                 " id="Control Budget">
        Control Budget
      </th>
      <th class="Design
                 chgWidth" id="Design">
        Design
        <input value="1303" type="">
      </th>
      <th class="DisciplineCheck
                 chgWidth" id="Discipline Check">
        Discipline Check
        <input value="1304" type="">
      </th>
      <th class="ClientReview
                 chgWidth" id="Client Review">
        Client Review
        <input value="1305" type="">
      </th>
      <th class="Issue
                 chgWidth" id="Issue">
        Issue
        <input value="1306" type="">
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="6"></td>
      <td class="percent">65.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
      <td class="percent">15.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
      <td class="percent">15.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
      <td class="percent">5.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td class="Cell+-1" hidden="true">672168</td>
      <td class="Cell+0">02-Project Controls - -</td>
      <td class="Cell+1">J11</td>
      <td class="Cell+2">desc1</td>
      <td class="Cell+3">23</td>
      <td class="Cell+4">0</td>
      <td class="Cell+5">23</td>
      <td class="percent">
        <input id="Cell+6" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="21.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
      <td class="percent">
        <input id="Cell+7" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="46.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
      <td class="percent">
        <input id="Cell+8" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="29.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
      <td class="percent">
        <input id="Cell+9" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="2.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>



</div>
<div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="titleRow">
        <td colspan="100%">J29 - Narrative Design Multidiscipline</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="colNames">
        <th class="r_id
                 " id="r_id" hidden="true">
          r_id
        </th>
        <th class="WBS
                 " id="WBS">
          WBS
        </th>
        <th class="ActivityCode
                 " id="Activity Code">
          Activity Code
        </th>
        <th class="PTTDescription
                 " id="PTT Description">
          PTT Description
        </th>
        <th class="OriginalBudget
                 " id="Original Budget">
          Original Budget
        </th>
        <th class="PCN
                 " id="PCN">
          PCN
        </th>
        <th class="ControlBudget
                 " id="Control Budget">
          Control Budget
        </th>
        <th class="Design
                 chgWidth" id="Design">
          Design
          <input value="1346" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="DisciplineCheck
                 chgWidth" id="Discipline Check">
          Discipline Check
          <input value="1347" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="IDC
                 chgWidth" id="IDC">
          IDC
          <input value="1348" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="ClientReview
                 chgWidth" id="Client Review">
          Client Review
          <input value="1349" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="Issue
                 chgWidth" id="Issue">
          Issue
          <input value="1350" type="">
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
        <td class="percent">60.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">10.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">10.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">15.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">5.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td class="Cell+-1" hidden="true">672169</td>
        <td class="Cell+0">03-System Staging - -</td>
        <td class="Cell+1">J29</td>
        <td class="Cell+2">desc2</td>
        <td class="Cell+3">12</td>
        <td class="Cell+4">0</td>
        <td class="Cell+5">12</td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+6" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="10.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+7" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="20.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+8" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="30.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+9" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="20.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+10" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="20.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
  <div>
    <input class="stepidhere" type="text" />
  </div>



</div>
<div>


  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="titleRow">
        <td colspan="100%">J22 - SOW/Construction Bid Pkg Assembly - Const Bid Package assembly and Scope write-up - SDC</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="colNames">
        <th class="r_id
                 " id="r_id" hidden="true">
          r_id
        </th>
        <th class="WBS
                 " id="WBS">
          WBS
        </th>
        <th class="ActivityCode
                 " id="Activity Code">
          Activity Code
        </th>
        <th class="PTTDescription
                 " id="PTT Description">
          PTT Description
        </th>
        <th class="OriginalBudget
                 " id="Original Budget">
          Original Budget
        </th>
        <th class="PCN
                 " id="PCN">
          PCN
        </th>
        <th class="ControlBudget
                 " id="Control Budget">
          Control Budget
        </th>
        <th class="DevelopPkg
                 chgWidth" id="Develop Pkg">
          Develop Pkg
          <input value="1337" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="DisciplineCheck
                 chgWidth" id="Discipline Check">
          Discipline Check
          <input value="1338" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="ClientReview
                 chgWidth" id="Client Review">
          Client Review
          <input value="1339" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="Issue
                 chgWidth" id="Issue">
          Issue
          <input value="1340" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="BidTime
                 chgWidth" id="Bid Time">
          Bid Time
          <input value="1341" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="BidEvaluation
                 chgWidth" id="Bid Evaluation">
          Bid Evaluation
          <input value="1342" type="">
        </th>
        <th class="Award
                 chgWidth" id="Award">
          Award
          <input value="1343" type="">
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="6"></td>
        <td class="percent">60.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">15.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">10.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">5.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">0.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">10.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">0.00<i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td class="Cell+-1" hidden="true">672170</td>
        <td class="Cell+0">03-System Staging - -</td>
        <td class="Cell+1">J22</td>
        <td class="Cell+2">werwererwerwewerwerweerwerere</td>
        <td class="Cell+3">6</td>
        <td class="Cell+4">0</td>
        <td class="Cell+5">6</td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+6" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="10.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+7" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="10.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+8" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="10.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+9" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="20.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+10" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="30.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+11" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="10.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+12" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="10.00" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 235, 156);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td class="Cell+-1" hidden="true">672171</td>
        <td class="Cell+0">03-System Staging - -</td>
        <td class="Cell+1">J22</td>
        <td class="Cell+2">just typing this line in to see how long my text fields should be</td>
        <td class="Cell+3">12</td>
        <td class="Cell+4">0</td>
        <td class="Cell+5">12</td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+6" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+7" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+8" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+9" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+10" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+11" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
        <td class="percent">
          <input id="Cell+12" class="input-sm-np pClass" value="0" min="0" max="100" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" type="number"><i class="fa fa-percent" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks.  that worked.